# How to manage UI for IPhone 7 and 7 plus in xamarin ios?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I have a `UITableView` control in my screen. I created a `UITableview cell` for it. In which I have some `labels`, `button` and another `view` in it which also contains some more controls like `label`. This inner `view` visible only user click on `button` in cell. Everything is working fine. I designed the view according to iPphone6.

But when I am trying to run it on iPhone 6 plus or 7 plus, controls are not managing itself according to device. It's working fine in iPhone6 and 7 but in iPhone plus models it's not looking good.

I'm trying to manage constraints for the controls but not able to manage it.
Please update how I can manage the UI so that it can look perfect in iPhone 6, 7 and 6 plus and 7 plus models.

[image]

[image]

Comment: add screenshot for iphone 6 and 6 plus so will give you proper answer.

Comment: If you do not set the constrains in code there will be no difference to native iOS development. So two options left: 1) edit you constraints with the Xamarin iOS designer or 2) edit your constraints with Xcodes Interface builder, which I recommend.

Comment: Is the constraint set correctly? Is the same happen when you preview in storyboard editor or only happen in simulator/device?

Comment: There was some problem with constraints. I managed it via code

Comment: @anand If you resolved this issue, please close the question or answer it yourself and accept your own answer. This avoids people searching for unresolved questions from finding this post. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I am also struggling to manage UI design in both 6s and 6s plus models. Have you find any solution for managing designs in both models. Please let me know.